# Allocate first pointer of 2d-array to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

im new to C so "allocate" may not be the right word to use here.

Say i have a function like this, which returns a pointer to a pointer of int.

```
int **foo(){} //I wouldn't care much what this function does
```

in main() function i defined an array like this

```
int playground[10][10];
playground=foo();
```

But the compiler warned me of this error :

> assignment to expression with array type
>     playground = foo();

What is actually wrong here? As far as i know, because **playground** is a 2d Array so it would be a pointer which points to pointer of int, which exactly what function **foo()** returns.

Can someone explain ? Many thanks!

Comment: just define playground as int **playground; but you may need to allocate space for the 2d array inside foo().

Comment: Thank yoi, i took care of the memory problem, but still wondering why my way didnt work, because as far as i know, when you write "playground" it actually means the pointer to the first element of array, so why it didnt work in the example ?

Comment: playground[10][10] is a 2d array, not a pointer to a 2d array, but foo() returns a pointer to a 2d array.

Comment: @Shiping Assuming i want to keep defining my 2d array this way, is there any work-around to refer "playground" to a 2d array i get from foo() ? Because 2d array can't be returned, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't pointers. In particular, an array is not an assignable lvalue, so an array name can never be alone on the left side of an assignment statement. You want:

```
int **playground;
playground = foo();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i always thought that when you write "playground", c will give you the pointer to the first element of array ?

Comment: Not always. For example, when the array is operated on by `sizeof`. Check out the [comp.lang.c FAQ section on Arrays & Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) to get all the details you need.

Comment: in this case, it points to the location of the array for data/value retrieval, but you can't change it to let it point to somewhere else.